# Non parenthesized parameters led to an endless recursive call

Tags: haskell

I'm learning how to use Haskell and I came across a roadblock which took me a while to overcome. It had to do with a recursive call on a function that calculates the Integer square root of any given Nat.

My question isn't about the code itself but on Haskell's behavior when it comes to taking parameters for recursive calls (or regular function calls).

This was my original code:

```
raizAux2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
raizAux2 n i = 
    if i^2 > n 
      then i-1
    else raizAux2 n i+1
```

Which looped forever becase Haskell ignored the i+1 call as it only took the "i" argument, ignoring the "+1" part altogether, leaving the function looping indefinitely. The solution was to parenthesize (i+1).

[**Edit**: Thanks to @sepp2k's reply, now I understand nothing gets *ignored*, it just gets interpreted according to the language inherent rules of precedence.]

```
raizAux2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
raizAux2 n i = 
    if i^2 > n 
      then i-1
    else raizAux2 n (i+1)
```

So my question is (and I know it might be really dumb to ask): Is this behavior inherent to functional programming? Why did Haskell decide to *ignore* the "+1" part and just take the "i"? And finally, what happens to the ignored parts of any given parameter. Are they disposed of immediately?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not ignored, it just has a different precedence than you expect. `f x + 1` is equivalent to `(f x) + 1`, so instead of adding 1 to x and applying f to that, it adds 1 to the result of `f x`. But since `f x` loops infinitely in your case, it never gets to that part.

This isn't a property of functional programming so much as the precedence rules of Haskell (and other languages with ML-like syntax).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @sepp2k. It is very helpful to have these small details in mind from the get go. :)